# Play/loop video from-to frame

Tags: javascript, html5-video

How I can play or loop video from one to another frame?

For example, play video from frame 156 to frame 195, or loop between these frames all the time.

Is there any JS library or something?

Comment: If you can somehow know which frame the video is currently at (idk if there is a function to support framecounting natively) then you could setup a few `eventHandlers` to keep the video from reaching over a certain frame and setting its position back to where you want. Keep one thing in mind though, browsers are a bit wonky when it comes to their `precision` in video playbacks so you might get a few frames off (up to about 600 millisec) depending on browser in both cutoff and start

Comment: @Dellirium thanks for the answer...so, maybe the best idea will be to have multiple videos and to switch them on some trigger, because right now I have one video and need to fully control it (like, play from frame 50 to frame 100, after that loop from frame 100 to frame 134, after that play from frame 134 to frame 100 in reverse...)

Comment: Multiple videos is definitively the best option if you can have it. Video starting/pausing in browsers is very inprecise, if you need that level of control u need more videos.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple looping solution from w3school.

Maybe this will help.

```html
<video controls loop>
  <source src="[put source here]" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

source : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_loop.asp